# Performance de file_get_contents()

Tags: php, wordpress

Estou pegando o conteúdo de um Feed RSS gerado pelo Wordpress, e o mesmo tem trazido as informações com um pouco de atraso (segundo o Google PageSpeed Insights, está tendo um delay de 1 a 2.5s).

Gostaria de saber se isso é devido ao meu trecho de código ou do Feed RSS em si.

PS: Ao comentar este trecho de código, o site flui normalmente.

```
$feed = file_get_contents('http://blog.exal.com.br/feed');
$rss = new SimpleXmlElement($feed);

$contadorNoticias = 0;

foreach($rss->channel->item as $post) {

    if($contadorNoticias < 3){
        $imagemNoticia = "/common/function/thumb.php?largura=730&amp;altura=405&amp;crop=true&amp;imgCrop=center&amp;url=".$post->enclosure['url'];
        $listaNoticia .= "
        <div class=\"col-sm-4\">
            <a class=\"itemOpacity\" href=\"".$post->link."\" title=\"Ir para: Notícias > ".$post->title."\">
                <img src=\"".$imagemNoticia."\" alt=\"Imagem: ".$post->title."\" class=\"img-responsive\" />
                <h2>".$post->title."</h2>
                <p>".str_truncate(strip_tags($post->description),220)." [...]</p>
            </a>
        </div>"; 
    }
    else{
        break;
    }

    $contadorNoticias++;
}

echo $listaNoticia;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso ocorre unicamente porque você está baixando um conteúdo externo. Sempre que executa isso ele irá se conectar com o `http://blog.exal.com.br/feed`, irá procurar o IP do endereço e se conectar, então irá aguardar a resposta do website e obter os dados, fazer o download, depois executar o resto do código baseado no que foi obtido, simples assim.

Se você fizer um:

```
curl "http://blog.exal.com.br/feed/" -o /dev/null -w "Tempo para conectar: %{time_connect}\nTempo para começar transferencia: %{time_starttransfer}\nTempo Total: %{time_total}"
```

No Windows utilize: `-o null`, para remover o alerta de `Failed writing body` porque não existe `/dev/null` no Windows. :S

Isso irá informar o tempo que levou para o seu servidor (ou qualquer dispositivo) se conectar e obter os dados do outro website.

---

Nos meus testes:

```
Tempo para conectar: 0.154
Tempo para começar transferencia: 1.501
Tempo Total: 1.878

Tempo para conectar: 0.031
Tempo para começar transferencia: 1.406
Tempo Total: 1.406

Tempo para conectar: 0.137
Tempo para começar transferencia: 1.184
Tempo Total: 1.557

...
```

---

- `Tempo para conectar` (`time_connect`): indica o tempo que demora para o CURL criar a conexão TCP até se conectar corretamente com o servidor (ou proxy).
- `Tempo para começar transferencia` (`time_starttransfer`): indica o tempo que demora para o CURL receber o primeiro byte de resposta, isso é o tempo que demorou para que o CURL começasse a receber algum dado.
- `Tempo Total` (`time_total`): indica o tempo total que demorou para obter o resultado.

---

### Onde esta o problema?

O principal problema está no próprio website que gera o feed (`http://blog.exal.com.br/feed`), uma vez que ele demora em média 1350 milissegundos para retornar as informações, ou para começar a retornar, assim demorando que o seu website também exiba tais informações.

### Como resolver?

Depende, não há informações suficientes na pergunta, a pergunta na verdade foi apenas "Gostaria de saber se isso é devido ao meu trecho de código ou do Feed RSS em si.", isto está respondido acima.

Entretanto, existe algumas soluções que pode fazer NO SEU LADO.

**Utilize cache:**

Porque precisa se conectar toda hora com o outro site? Ele atualiza de quanto em quanto tempo?

Uma opção é criar fazer um `cronjob` e salvar num arquivo `/cache/feed` e carrega-lo sempre.

Crie um `atualizaFeed.php`:

```
$getFeed = file_get_contents('http://blog.exal.com.br/feed');
file_put_contents('alguma/pasta/feed.xml', $getFeed);
```

Crie um `cronjob`, exemplo: `* * * * * php atualizaFeed.php`, pode usar o `crontab -e` para editar via `vi`.

> Você pode simplesmente esquecer o PHP e utilizar diretamente: `* * * * * curl "http://blog.exal.com.br/feed/" -o /alguma/pasta/feed.xml`. ;)

Depois basta que carregue as informações do arquivo que é atualizado a cada minuto, utilizando:

```
$feed = file_get_contents('alguma/pasta/feed.xml');
$rss = new SimpleXmlElement($feed);

//...
```

O arquivo `alguma/pasta/feed.xml` será sempre atualizado, a cada um minuto. Logo, quando o usuário acessar a página será lido o arquivo que já está no seu servidor, isto é infinitamente mais rápido do que esperar a resposta do servidor externo a cada conexão.

> Você também pode criar um banco de dados se quiser e ir atualizando quando houver novas publicações, enfim, várias opções...

Comment: Obrigado pelo detalhamento, @Inkeliz! Me deu ideia para outra solução. Como o WP está na mesma hospedagem do site (apenas separados pelo subdomínio), resolvi ao invés de trazer os posts via file_get_contents, fazer a consulta diretamente no banco de dados. E deu certo! ;-)